# How do I update the values of formArray from a component in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

Good day guys, please I am having issues updating values in a formArray from my angular 6 component. I have tried using setValue() and patchValue() no one of them is working. Below is my code

```
 this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
       locationRequests: this._formBuilder.array([
          this._formBuilder.group({
          location: '',
          item_category: '',
          items: '',
          quantity: '',
          packaging: '',
          unit_of_measurement: '',
    });
        ])
    });
```

I want to set value to each of the fields from my component, i have tried

```
this.form.patchValue({
 locationRequests: this._formBuilder.array([
          this._formBuilder.group({
          location: 'New York',
          item_category: 2,
          items: 1,
          quantity: 500,
          packaging: 1,
          unit_of_measurement: 'PCS',
}
});
```

I have also tried using setValue function still did not work. I have searched online and all the answers aren't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while patching use this.

`this.form.patchValue({
      locationRequests: [
               {
               location: 'New York',
               item_category: 2,
               items: 1,
               quantity: 500,
               packaging: 1,
               unit_of_measurement: 'PCS',
     }]
});`

You don't need to specify `this._formBuilder.group` or `this._formBuilder.array` while patching values.

Comment: Thank you so much @sachinGupta for this answer, I have been battling with this for the past 24 hours. I just tried your code and it worked very well.